# SQL query to add values of two columns containing null values?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Given table:

```
    ID   ONE   TWO
    X1   15    15
    X2   10    -
    X3   -     20
```

This query:

```
SELECT (ONE + TWO) FROM (TABLE)
```

Just returns the sum of `X1`'s values but not the others since at least one column has a null value. How can I still add them even if there is a null? i.e. consider the null as a 0 maybe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT (COALESCE(ONE, 0) + COALESCE(TWO, 0)) FROM (TABLE)
```

`COALESCE` will return the first non-null value found in the parameters from left to right. So, when the first field is null, it will take the 0.

That way, `X2` will result in `10 + 0 = 10`

Answer (score 1):

there is already a good answer, but I think it is worth mention to the antonpug (in case he doesn't know) that the reason why this is happening is that NULL is not a value that can be compared or summed.

NULL isn't 0 or '' (empty string), so every operation involving NULL will result NULL (10 + NULL = NULL), even (NULL=NULL) will evaluate to FALSE

Comment: In Oracle, the empty string is NULL. This differs from the standard and other RDBMs. In Oracle `select 'true' from dual where '' is null` returns true and `select 'true' from dual where '' = ''` does not return a row. Because of this, the concatenation operator `||` will only return null if both sides are null. `select null||'Hello World!' from dual` gives the string "Hello World!".